# "We took turns in pushing the bike along." meaning?

Tags: meaning

I cannot understand the following sentence:

> We took turns in pushing the bike along.

About "take turns" in the dictionary has brought:

> **take turns** also **take it in turns** (British English) if two or more people take turns doing work, using something etc, they do it one
>   after the other, for example in order to share the work or play
>   fairly.

Comment: It just means they alternately pushed the bike along: first one pushed, then the other took over and pushed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about how two people would manage a bike that for some reason could not be ridden.

It would be awkward if they both held on to it, the difficulty of coordinating their effort would waste any benefit of cooperating.

On the other hand, if one person did all the work, that would feel unfair.

So, first one person would "push it along" (that is, walk next to the bike, holding it by the handlebars) and the other person would just walk nearby; then after a little while, they would switch, and the second person would push and the first would walk freely.  Every so often, they would switch back: "taking turns".